# Firebase currentUser and onAuthStateChanged

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am developing an app using react native, every time I refresh the app on the emulator in onAuthStateChanged and currentUser from firebase I get null.

I have read about waiting onAuthStateChanged to get a status update but I never do, so I guess I misconfigured something.

I am using expo 44, react 17, firebase 9.6.5 but in compat mode (planning in fully migrate later)

My first attempt of solution was trying to add persistence: firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/functions";
import "firebase/compat/storage";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebase/firebaseConfig";

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.firestore();
firebase.functions();
firebase.storage();
firebase.auth();

firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
    console.log("onAuthStateChanged called: ", user);
    if (user) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@isLoggedIn', '1');
    } else {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@isLoggedIn', '0');
    }
});

export default firebase;
```

But I get an error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.storage.setItem')
at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-cff4f2fd.js:5248:0 in verifyBeforeUpdateEmail
at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-cff4f2fd.js:5420:12 in _fromIdTokenResponse
at http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:183132:41 in _set
at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-cff4f2fd.js:1414:55 in newData.some$argument_0
at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-cff4f2fd.js:2060:1 in <global>
at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-cff4f2fd.js:2047:30 in _isIOS
at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-cff4f2fd.js:1890:4 in PersistenceUserManager.create
at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-cff4f2fd.js:1890:4 in PersistenceUserManager.create
```

to Login I use:

```
userCredential = firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, this.state.password);
```

Comment: As you're using Expo, try to replace `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`   with  `expo-secure-store` https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore which optimize to work with web also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same issue. I solved it by adding `"firebase": "^8.9.1"` to package.json, running `yarn install` and changing the import `import firebase from "firebase"` (remove all the other imports you have). Apparently selective imports have a bug in v8, but at least it works well :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I end up moving my code completely to v9 (without compat) and it works

Comment: Hi, Eduardo, can you possibly elaborate on what you did to get it to work. I am on v9 without compat and I am still getting the same error that you are getting.